# Добавлять просмотр в mysql при открытии страницы

Tags: mysql, php, sql

В модуле со статьями хочу заносить каждый просмотр в базу. Пишу следующее:

```
$path=$_GET['path'];
while (mysql_query("UPDATE `paper` SET `hits` = `hits` + 1 WHERE `path` = $path"));
```

Но значение не обновляется. Где я не прав? Где свернул не туда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй сделать так

1. print("UPDATE `paper` SET `hits` = `hits` + 1 WHERE `path` = $path") и будет выведен результирующий запрос
2. его попробовать выполнить к примеру из phpmyadmin

Есть подозрение что тут `path` = $path нужно бы кавычек добавить.

Вот так `$path=$_GET['path'];` делать плохо, вашу систему уже можно ломать, допустим я передам в адресной строке `path=123123213213`, что случится?
Лучше уж `path` преобразовывать или проверку на существование делать.

Comment: Пишу:

$path=$_GET['path'];
while (mysql_query("UPDATE `paper` SET `hits` = `hits` + 1 WHERE `path` = '$path'"));

Но условие выполняется циклично. Как обновить только один раз?

Comment: @tiNtw не связываться с while, очевидно.